# Is there a way to access protected vector size via main function without turning it to public?

Tags: c++, class, vector, polymorphism

I've been working on a Shape program lately ( Some of you might remember my other questions about this... ;/ ) And I have a tiny problem which I want to fix.

In my Menu class, which holds all the functions related to the menu. I have a unique_ptr vector with the type of my base class Shape which holds all of the newly created objects ( Circles, Rectangles, ect )

```
protected:
    vector<unique_ptr<Shape>> _shapes;
```

One of the functions that I want to create is supposed to change the values of the variables in a given shape based on it's index. To do so, I was planning to print the vector to the user, and then let him to choose the index of the shape that he wants to change.

```
void Menu::printShapes() const
{
    int i = 0;
    for (auto p = _shapes.begin(); p != _shapes.end(); p++, i++)
    {
        cout << i + " ";
        (*p)->printDetails();
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The problems lays in my main program which is going to use my Menu functions. Because I don't want the user to be able to enter values which are outside of my vector, I have to check if the given input is between 0 and the size of the vector. But I cannot access this info from my main function without making the vector public or make a return statement from the printShapes() function, which will make the code messy and not intuitive as I want it to be.

So my question is: Is there a way to find the size of the vector at the Menu function from the main function without making the changes I stated above? Because in the end I want to be able to just do `menu.printShapes()` and then let the user to choose the index of the shape that he wants to change

this is my main function as of now:

```
    Menu menu;
    int input = 0, wait = 0;
    while (input != 4)
    {
        cout << "1: Add New Shape: " << endl;
        cout << "2: Modify Existing Shape: " << endl;
        cout << "3: Delete All Shapes: " << endl;
        cout << "4: Exit: " << endl;
        while (input < MIN || input > MAX)
        {
            cin >> input;
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cin >> wait;
        }
        switch (input)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                cout << "1: Circle: " << endl;
                cout << "2: Rectangle: " << endl;
                cout << "3: Triangle: " << endl;
                cout << "4: Arrow: " << endl;
                while (input < MIN || input > MAX)
                {
                    cin >> input;
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    std::cin >> wait;
                }
                menu.createShape(input);
            }
            case 2:
            {
                /*
                I want to be able to access the size of the vector from here
                So I could do something like that:
                menu.printShapes();
                while (input < 0 || input > vectorSize)
                {
                    :Get the index of the shape that the user wants to modify
                }
                Instant of doing
                size = menu.printShapes();
                */
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are ways (look up the term *getter*), but why would you want to? Perhaps you should think of your classes more in terms of *behavior* instead of simple containers for variables and functions?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve here. There's too little relevant info and too much distracting stuff. For example, remove all that shape stuff, it's not relevant what a vector stores when the question is whether an index is valid. Also, could you show working code that you want to improve? With that, it might even be better to take this to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sadly I was asked to it like that ( With menu class ) To help me and learn about polymorphism and whatnot a bit more.

Comment: You just need to add your method `Menu::shapes_count`

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Check the edit I've made

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that do works, But then if I want to make turn this project to a library, then when I'll use it I will have to create a variable for the size each time. And I feel like it's not good enough and intuitive

Comment: No, I suggested a *method* (the better word is *member function*) not a *variable*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but then I have to save it's return value into a variable :(

Comment: No, you simply define `size_t Menu::shapes_count() const { return _shapes.size(); }` ; no extra variable is involved. And you don't need to "save" that value

Comment: `while (input < 0 || input > menu.shapes_count())` I mean you have to get the value somehow. I don't really understand your confusion or the issue. This question has too much information for a [mcve] and too little for a codereview, plus it's on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

You're way overthinking this.

You just need to add a public function that returns the current size of the vector:

```
// Declaration in your class
size_t numberOfShapes() const;

// Definition
size_t Menu::numberOfShapes() const
{
   return _shapes.size();
}
```

. Then, when you want to know the size, call that function.

```
menu.printShapes();
while (input < 0 || input > menu.numberOfShapes())
{
   // Get the index of the shape that the user wants to modify
}
```

Simple!

By the way, I think you meant `>=` there, not `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a few options; depending on the details of the modify-existing-shape operation.

The easiest thing would probably be to have your Menu type expose a method to tell you how many shapes it's managing. I agree you shouldn't make the vector public because the program doesn't need to know it's a vector specially, but if "knowing how many existing shapes the menu is managing" is a requirement (which it seems to be) then exposing it seems reasonable.

Alternatively, depending on the return type of the modify operation you could return an optional or a variant. If you have 7 shapes and I ask you to modify the 6th then you might tell me that it worked or maybe the new dimensions, but if I ask you to modify the 9th you might tell me it's an invalid index.

The difference becomes whether to obligate the caller to be informed and ask a valid question, or whether you want to be more robust and answer and handle a broader domain of questions. I don't think it makes a big difference in this case but I tend toward the second kind of solution simply because it means *any* potential caller is protected from going out of range instead of *all* of then having to check the count then do their own validation.